# Problem with output for List to Dictionary for Fantasy Game Inventory

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, dictionary

I'm working on the Automate the boring stuff with Python book. I get the intended results but I also get an added `None` value. The instructions are as follows:

List to Dictionary Function for Fantasy Game Inventory:

Imagine that a vanquished dragon’s loot is represented as a list of strings like this:

`dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']`

Write a function named  `addToInventory(inventory, addedItems)`, where the  `inventory`  parameter is a dictionary representing the player’s inventory (like in the previous project) and the  `addedItems`  parameter is a list like  `dragonLoot`. The  `addToInventory()`  function should return a dictionary that represents the updated inventory. Note that the addedItems list can contain multiples of the same item. Your code could look something like this:

```
def addToinventory(inventory, addedItems):

inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
dragonloot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
inv = addToinventory(inv, dragonloot)
displayInventory(inv)
```

The previous program (with your  `displayInventory()`  function from the previous project) would output the following:

```
Inventory:
45 gold coin
1 rope
1 ruby
1 dagger
Total number of items: 48
```

My code is as follows

```
def addToinventory(inventory, addedItems):
    for i in addedItems:
        inventory.setdefault(i, 0)
        inventory[i] += 1
    itotal = 0
    for k, v in inventory.items():
        print(str(v), k)
        itotal += v
    print('Total number of items', itotal)


inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
dragonloot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
print(addToinventory(inv, dragonloot))
```

My output is like this:

```
45 gold coin
1 rope
1 dagger
1 ruby
Total number of items 48
None
```

At the end of the output, I have a dangling `None` . I quite don't understand why?

Comment: Can you make sure the indentation on your code is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the line, `print(addToinventory(inv, dragonloot))`.

Here, you are trying to print the `return value` of `addToinventory()`. And `addToinventory()` doesn't return anything so you are printing `None`.

To get rid of `None`, replace `print(addToinventory(inv, dragonloot))` with `addToinventory(inv, dragonloot)`.

Answer (score 0):

The None output is because you are printing the operation of the addToinventory function and it is not returning anything, which is why it returns None by default.
Change your function to this:

```
def addToinventory(inventory, addedItems):
    for i in addedItems:
        inventory.setdefault(i, 0)
        inventory[i] += 1
    return inventory
```

I don't know how you have your displayInventory function but here I leave you a solution:

```
def displayInventory(inventory):
    print("Inventory:")
    item_total = 0
    for k, v in inventory.items():
        print('%s %s' % (v,k))
        item_total += v
    print("Total number of items: %s" % item_total)
```

change this line of your code:

```
print(addToinventory(inv, dragonloot))
```

For this:

```
inv = addToinventory(inv, dragonloot)
```

and add this other one which will print the inventory:

```
displayInventory(inv)
```

output:

```
Inventory:
45 gold coin
1 rope
1 dagger
1 ruby
Total number of items: 48
```